# how to restrict one table primary key should reference to another table exact number of foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I want to refer an exact number of foreign keys of one table to one primary key in another table.as an example if we get the exact number as three.one primary key should connect just three foreign keys in another table. I use **USER** table to store user details and **PRODUCT** table to store users' buying products details. if **USER** table has the primary key as **ID** and **PRODUCT** table has foreign key reference to **USER** table via **User_ID** column. one user id(ID column in USER table) should limit to an exact number of three records in **PRODUCT** table.simply, the user can buy at most three product, not beyond that. can I do that in MySQL?

Comment: Please provide example table data to demonstrate what you mean.

Comment: Also, a primary key does not "reference" anything.

Comment: is it understandable now.can you get an idea what I am trying to ask? @Dai

Comment: It's still unclear. Please provide **sample data**, showing actual rows that demonstrate the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to write a trigger to do this in MySQL. Here's an example:

```
mysql> DELIMITER ;;

mysql> CREATE TRIGGER limit123 BEFORE INSERT ON Product
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Product WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id) > 2)
    THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Only three products per user allowed';
    END IF;
END;;

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> INSERT INTO Product SET user_id=1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO Product SET user_id=1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO Product SET user_id=1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO Product SET user_id=1;
ERROR 1644 (45000): Only three products per user allowed
```